# Angular Material dialog not receiving MAT_DIALOG_DATA when created from canActivate

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-material, angular-dependency-injection

I'm trying to read a query param on a given route in the `canActivate` function and if it's not there, show a modal saying that it's not going to work ok.

When I think more about this, because it's only supposed to happen when the app is started for the first time, I think I'll move the logic in a provider with APP_INITIALIZER.

That said, I'm quite frustrated that I haven't been able to inject the `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` properly and I'd like to:

- 1. Understand why
- 2. Find a workaround

Before I share a minimal repro, let me walk you through the code I wrote:

```js
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(MatDialogModule),
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: '',
        component: FooComponent,
        canActivate: [
          () => {
            const dialog = inject(MatDialog);
            dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
              data: {
                helloWorld: true,
              },
            });
            return true;
          },
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

I make sure to import `MatDialogModule` and then I define a dummy route to have a `canActivate`. In here, I open up a dialog in which I try to pass some data.

The dialog component is defined as the following:

```js
export class DialogComponent {
  @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public dialogData: any;
}
```

and the view

```html
Data received in the dialog:

<pre>{{ dialogData | json }}</pre>
```

The issue being that `dialogData` is always undefined here.

---

I suspect that from the `canActivate`, I get a different injector and it's somehow messing up with this idea of launching a dialog with data from here. But it should be as easy as swapping the injector? Or even overriding manually the injector to define the `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` token myself?

Well I've tried that too, and it doesn't work:

```js
const newInjector = Injector.create({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
      useValue: {
        helloWorld: true,
      },
    },
  ],
  parent: inject(Injector),
});

dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  data: {
    helloWorld: true,
  },
  injector: newInjector
});
```

I have also tried passing the `ViewContainerRef` out of desperation but I did not expect that to work.

What am I missing here? Can anyone explain and give a workaround?

Here's a [Stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ydcvqh?file=src%2Fmain.ts).

**EDIT:**

I just tried to migrate my code to the `APP_INITIALIZER` and I've got the exact same issue, so I'm out of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update the dialog component code, we need to use the injector inside the constructor for dependency injection to work I think!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogModule, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog.component.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, MatDialogModule],
})
export class DialogComponent {
  public dialogData: any;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any) {
    this.dialogData = data;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-mkhgtv?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fdialog%2Fdialog.component.ts)

Comment: Well, thank you so much. It's a mix of I've been using the "new" `inject` a lot lately instead of using the constructor injection and I made a mix by copying the @Inject from the doc + tired on a Friday afternoon... Thanks again

Comment: @maxime1992 I'm having the same problem sometimes :) You're welcome!